# How do I cut off a file name with three dots (...) in a custom button?

Tags: jquery, css, button, text

This is the code I have for the button and how the function is filling its content:

```
<div id="slikadiv">
                <input type="file" name="real_file" id="real_file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" value="" hidden="hidden">
                <button type="button" id="custom_button" class="inputslika">Izaberi sliku</button>
            </div>

[...]

function dodajSliku() {
        $("#custom_button").click(function() {
            $("#real_file").click();
        })

        $("#real_file").change(function() {
           if ($("#real_file").val()) {
            let vrednost = $("#real_file").val();
            vrednost = vrednost.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
            $("#custom_button").text(vrednost);
            $("#custom_button").css("background-image", "url('../slike/finish.svg')");
            $("#custom_button").css("color", "black");
           } else {
            $("#real_file").val() = "";
           }
        })
    }
    dodajSliku();
```

This is the CSS for the div and button:

```
#slikadiv {
    width:250px;
}

.inputslika {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1.5pt solid black;
    background-image: url("../slike/add.svg");
    background-size: 32px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: calc(100% - 8px) center;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: small;
    text-indent: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see, I've tried the ellipsis text overflow option with the needed arguments, but it's not exactly working. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Is it you want?

```js
function dodajSliku() {
        $("#custom_button").click(function() {
            $("#real_file").click();
        })

        $("#real_file").change(function() {
           if ($("#real_file").val()) {
              let vrednost = $("#real_file").val();
              vrednost = vrednost.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
              $("#custom_button").text(vrednost);
              $("#custom_button").css("background-image", "url('../slike/finish.svg')");
              $("#custom_button").css("color", "black");
           } else {
              $("#real_file").val() = "";
           }
        })
    }
    dodajSliku();
```

```css
#slikadiv {
    width:200px;
}

.inputslika {
    display:block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1.5pt solid black;
    background-image: url("../slike/add.svg");
    background-size: 32px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: calc(100% - 8px) center;
    color: black;    
    font-size: small;    
    padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="slikadiv">
    <input type="file" name="real_file" id="real_file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" value="" hidden="hidden">
    <button type="button" id="custom_button" class="inputslika">Izaberi sliku</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for, thank you! It's not really working on my end though when I try to put it in the code, do you know why that is?

Comment: I only edit CSS. So please copy whole CSS and paste on your code.